# ASP.NET MVC Ajax.Begin form with many inputs (type=submit)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have an Ajax form :

```
<%using (Ajax.BeginForm(...)){%>
                    ...
   <input id="btn1" type="submit" value="OK1"/>
   <input id="btn2" type="submit" value="OK2"/>
<%} %>
```

both inputs do different jobs - is it possible to catch which input has been clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your input buttons different names:

```
<input id="btn1" type="submit" name="action1" value="OK1"/>
<input id="btn2" type="submit" name="action2" value="OK2"/>
```

And then in the controller action check if `action1` was clicked by looking at the request parameters (the name of the clicked button will be sent):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["action1"]))
    {
        // action1 was clicked
    }
    // ...
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
<input id="btnSubmit" name="pFormAction" type="submit" value="Submit" class="ym-button" />&nbsp;
<input id="btnSave" name="pFormAction" type="submit" value="Save" class="ym-button" />&nbsp;
<input type="reset" value="Clear" class="ym-button" />
```

and then in your repo:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Create(string pFormAction, V2WorksheetModel pWorksheet) { }
```

instead of having to use different names and not taking advantage of the model binding.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you have two buttons and then depending on what button was clicked you could set the action on the form:
I am using jQuery here to do this, but I think you can get the idea

```
$(function (){
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#form").attr
               (
                  "action",
                  "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {area="Area" })", 
               ).submit();
});
$("#btn2").click(function() {
    $("#form").attr
               (
                  "action",
                  "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new {area="Area" })", 
               ).submit();
});
```

});